# Нужна ли запятая в этом вопросительном предложении?

Tags: запятые

Запятая в предложении: Объясните, почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужна.

Розенталь:
Придаточное предложение, состоящее из одного только относительного слова или словосочетания и стоящее после главного предложения, запятой от него не отделяется, например:
*Он ушел и не сказал куда.

**Трудно сказать почему.

Знаешь что?**

Я не скажу какое, я говорю — большое несчастье.

Однажды, не помню по какому случаю, он заявил нам...*
То же самое, если имеется несколько относительных слов, выступающих в роли однородных членов, например:
*Не знаю почему и каким образом, но он вдруг очутился рядом со мной.

Позвонят — расспроси кто, по какому вопросу и сообщи на квартиру секретарю.*
Но если при относительном слове имеется примыкающее слово или частица, то запятая ставится, например:
*Я не очень хорошо знаю, что именно.

Я не помню, что еще.*